# ASP.NET User.Identity Get Migrated Field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm having a hell of a time trying to figure out the simplest task. I have successfully added my additional field to the AspNetUsers datatable using migrations, the new field being BRANCHID. All works great, but how do I display the field value for the logged in user in a simple label? I'm using vb with webforms.

In c# I can use the following:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());

var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);        

var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

GLOBAL.selectedBRANCHID  = currentUser.BRANCHID;
```

Does anybody know how I can do a similar task in vb??

Thanks in advance,

Nick.

Answer (score 0):

The default Visual Basic Windows Forms website has an ApplicationUserManager that you can use in the way that you would like.  The code in Visual Basic should be the following if used in one of the standard sites.

```
Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
Dim currentUser = manager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId())
GLOBAL.selectedBRANCHID = currentUser.BRANCHID
```

Although you could use something like this if needed to use the ApplicationDbContext directly:

```
Dim manager = New ApplicationUserManager(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(context.[Get](Of ApplicationDbContext)()))
```

This was found looking through the default code behind files in the default Visual Basic template for Web Forms in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Cheers Troy, I have tried your solution but now get the error BRANCHID is not a member of 'task(Of ApplicationUser)' ?? I can't for the life of me figure this one out. Here is my applicationuser code:

Comment: Public Class ApplicationUser
    Inherits IdentityUser
    Public Property BranchID() As String
        Get
            Return m_BranchID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Branch = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_BranchID As String

Comment: Public Function GenerateUserIdentity(manager As ApplicationUserManager) As ClaimsIdentity
        ' Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        Dim userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(Me, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
        ' Add custom user claims here
        Return userIdentity
    End Function

Comment: You may need to check the last post here [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/2013728.aspx?Customizing+Registration+form+in+Visual+Studio+2013+using+Asp+net+Identity+Web+Forms+Please+help+) and make sure that you have enabled migrations and updated the database.after editing ApplicationUser.  For more of a tutorial see this link: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun)